# Correct coding practices with strings, variables, loops - Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, performance

I am Android developer and not new to Java but I have some questions about best practices for performace. Ill give some examples from my code so you can decide.

**String concatenation**

```
url = "http://www.myserver." + domain + "/rss.php?"
+ rawType + rawCathegory + rawSubCathegory + rawLocality
+ rawRadius + rawKeyword + rawPriceFrom + rawPriceto;
```

As far as I know, this would create 11 string objects before my url variable is created, right?

Ive been taught to use StringBuilder, but my question is, *whats the minimum amount of strings to concat to make it efficient*? I think it wouldnt make much sense to use it concat two strings, right?

**Local variables**

Sometimes I try to "chain" method calls like so

```
FilterData.getInstance(context).getFilter(position).setActivated(isActivated);
```

to naively avoid variable allocation, but is it any faster than this?

```
FilterData filterData = FilterData.getInstance(context);
Filter filter = filterData.getFilter(position);
filter.setActivated(isActivated);
```

I believe it should as I save myself a local variable, but it becomes unreadable if the method names are long, etc.

**Loops**

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html says that enhanced for loops is 3x faster than the regular for loop, well that great and its easier to write anyways, *but, what if I need the index?* As far as I know, in enhaced for loop I need to keep track of it myself, like this

```
int index = 0;
for(Object obj : objects) {
    // do stuff
    index++;
}
```

Is this still faster than the regular loop?

```
for(int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
   // do stuff
}
```

I think that enhanced for loop maybe does optimisations about that limit, so maybe if the size() got optimized to this

```
int size = objects.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   // do stuff
}
```

How would that stand?

Thanks, I know this might be nitpicking and not make that much of a difference, but Ill rather learn such common tasks the right way.

Comment: Unless you notice your code being slow, don't sweat the small stuff. Don't [prematurely optimize](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), especially if it makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Strings:

Unless there's a loop involved, the compiler is clever enough to do the concatenation for you in the best way.

When you're looping, use StringBuilder or Buffer.

### Local Variables:

The two examples you give are identical. The memory still needs to be allocated even if you never give it a name.

### Loops:

Depending on the type of loop, using enhanced loops can give a massive or negligible improvement, it's best to read up on the one you're using.